# Standardise series of measurements into a single timeline in R

Tags: r

I have 6 large sets of measurements, for a variable recorded along a defined time period. The measurements come from several samples identified by treatments. Each set cover the time interval of the same lengths (48 hours) but rate of sampling is variable, this is the cause of different lengths of time series vectors. I would like to normalize the 7 sets of measurements in order to make calculations on the data and compare the treatments (e.g. average of the 7 series, sd, se, etc.).

In the example the 6 datasets are already `rbind` and the first 20 lines are displayed. The df has 3 columns: fractions of hours form 0 to 48h, the values of the continuous variable, and the period (1 to 6) to which the measurements belong.

Output: one dataframes with a time point every 30 minutes from 0 to 48 hours (0’, 30’, 60’, 90’, etc..), the period number, treatment and, in the column with the measured variable, a kind of interpolation between the 2 most proximal measurements originally recorded.

```
       hours   NH3_Raw period treatment
1  0.0648130 1089.1048      2        A-
2  0.2134490 2714.9061      1        B-
3  0.2655425  285.1279      2        A+
4  0.3136300 2180.8547      1        B+
5  0.3148610 1091.0609      5        A-
6  0.3155265  246.9763      4        A-
7  0.3155990  382.6315      3        A-
8  0.3156545  606.9789      6        A-
9  0.4562360  241.7223      5        A+
10 0.4570675  196.0806      4        A+
11 0.4571705  186.8204      3        A+
12 0.4572665  426.8417      6        A+
13 0.4644085 1516.0110      2        B-
14 0.5984205 1462.5251      4        B-
15 0.5986460 1318.1283      3        B-
16 0.5992145 2245.7524      5        B-
17 0.5996055 2570.2657      6        B-
18 0.6139253 1069.3496      1        A-
19 0.6645135 1686.3955      2        B+
20 0.7136957  380.8309      1        A+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data contains some combinations of "treatment" and "period" that only have a single time and value associated, so they cannot be interpolated. I'm assuming your real data has many more points, but I will have to create a larger data set here to show the solution.

```r
set.seed(69)

df <- data.frame(hours     = sort(runif(6000, 0, 48)),
                 NH3_Raw   = runif(6000, 100, 3000),
                 period    = sample(6, 6000, TRUE),
                 treatment = rep(c("A+", "A-", "B+", "B-"), 1500),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(df)
#>         hours   NH3_Raw period treatment
#> 1 0.006346922 1114.2207      1        A+
#> 2 0.016540099 2676.4284      2        A-
#> 3 0.032535430 2182.8841      6        B+
#> 4 0.035046034  441.9335      3        B-
#> 5 0.040023230  574.9462      6        A+
#> 6 0.040604230 1479.8270      6        A-
```

We set a vector of desired time intervals on which to interpolate:

```
desired_times <- seq(0.5, 48, 0.5)
```

Now we can create a new data frame of interpolated values like this:

```
new_df <- 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, paste(df$period, df$treatment)), function(x) {
    data.frame(hours = desired_times, 
               NH3_Raw = approx(x$hour, x$NH3_Raw, xout = desired_times)$y,
               period = x$period[1],
               treatment = x$treatment[1],
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}))

new_df <- `rownames<-`(new_df[order(new_df$hours),], seq(nrow(new_df)))
```

So your final result should look something like this:

```
head(new_df, 40)
#>    hours   NH3_Raw period treatment
#> 1    0.5        NA      1        A-
#> 2    0.5 2329.8554      1        A+
#> 3    0.5 1713.3148      1        B-
#> 4    0.5 2615.2987      1        B+
#> 5    0.5  530.4198      2        A-
#> 6    0.5  672.4222      2        A+
#> 7    0.5 1792.0053      2        B-
#> 8    0.5 1668.9496      2        B+
#> 9    0.5 1277.4349      3        A-
#> 10   0.5 1879.1142      3        A+
#> 11   0.5 2369.0511      3        B-
#> 12   0.5 1675.3803      3        B+
#> 13   0.5 1418.1820      4        A-
#> 14   0.5 2240.9298      4        A+
#> 15   0.5 2419.5662      4        B-
#> 16   0.5 1347.4588      4        B+
#> 17   0.5  545.1744      5        A-
#> 18   0.5 1791.8705      5        A+
#> 19   0.5 2412.4291      5        B-
#> 20   0.5 1780.1196      5        B+
#> 21   0.5  648.6645      6        A-
#> 22   0.5 1226.1662      6        A+
#> 23   0.5 1301.0647      6        B-
#> 24   0.5 1027.1567      6        B+
#> 25   1.0 1086.5756      1        A-
#> 26   1.0 1852.5523      1        A+
#> 27   1.0 2113.3323      1        B-
#> 28   1.0 1155.8553      1        B+
#> 29   1.0  959.9907      2        A-
#> 30   1.0 2417.1157      2        A+
#> 31   1.0 2499.6144      2        B-
#> 32   1.0 1449.8900      2        B+
#> 33   1.0  153.8517      3        A-
#> 34   1.0 2557.1666      3        A+
#> 35   1.0  990.5809      3        B-
#> 36   1.0 1703.8757      3        B+
#> 37   1.0 2240.0745      4        A-
#> 38   1.0 1448.1141      4        A+
#> 39   1.0 1946.3077      4        B-
#> 40   1.0  904.2440      4        B+
```

Comment: If I want to ask for a step more, in the same question, what shall I do? Edit the first post? Here in the comment section I don't have enough space

Comment: @johnposieux if it is complex you may need to ask a new question so that there is room to provide a new answer. If it is a short point you can ask in the comments.

Comment: it isn't complex, the instructions of stackoverflow suggest to edit the post.

Comment: @johnposieux I have completely rewritten my answer. I hope this gives you what you need.